# How to invalidate Breadcrumbs cache for child nodes on graphQl

Tags: caching, 9

I have for example **Node A** with alias ***node-a*** and **Node B** with alias ***node-a/node-b*** so on my **Node B** i have this breadcrumb ***Home > Node A > Node B***

GraphQl result:

```
"breadcrumb": [
                {
                    "text": "Home",
                    "url": {
                        "path": "/",
                        "routed": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "text": "Node A",
                    "url": {
                        "path": "http://example.com/node-a",
                        "routed": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "text": "Node B",
                    "url": {
                        "path": "",
                        "routed": true
                    }
                }
            ]
```

But when i change ***Node A*** title i get always the same result (breadcrumbs not changed), but when i re-save the **node A** or clear cache the graphQl result change.

Here is what i have tried:

1. Clear graphQl cache (results and definitions)on node update:

```
     /**
     * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
     */
    function MYMODULE_node_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
      // Clear graphql cache.
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $graphql_results_cache */
      $graphql_results_cache = \Drupal::service('cache.graphql.results');
      $graphql_results_cache->invalidateAll();
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $graphql_definitions_cache */
      $graphql_definitions_cache = \Drupal::service('cache.graphql.definitions');
      $graphql_definitions_cache->invalidateAll();
    }
```

it doesn't work !

2. Clear cache of all child node on node update like this:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
     */
    function MYMODULE_node_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
      $database = \Drupal::database();
      // Get the current node path alias.
      $alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')
        ->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $entity->id());
      // Get all node child of the current node.
      $child_nodes_alias = $database->select('path_alias', 'pa')->fields('pa', [
        'path',
        'alias',
      ])->condition('path', '/node/%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('alias', $alias . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
      // Invalidate cache for each node child of current node.
      foreach ($child_nodes_alias as $alias_data) {
        $nid = explode('/', $alias_data->path)[2] ?? NULL;
        if ($nid && $nid != $entity->id()) {
          $tags = ['node:' . $nid];
          Cache::invalidateTags($tags);
          \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache([$nid]);
        }
      }
    }
```

it doesn’t work also

3. I combined the two previous ways it doesn't work too.

When i clear all caches on node update it works, but it's not the best way it impact site cache.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

What is the best way to clear breadcrumbs cache, or child nodes without clear all site cache ?

**Edit:**
Thank you [@4K4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) for your comment, i did tried to add CacheTags too breadcrumb but i didn’t work either !

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_system_breadcrumb_alter(Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  // Append the current page title to the breadcrumb for non-admin routes.
  if ($breadcrumb && !\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {
    $links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $parameters = $link->getUrl()->getRouteParameters();
      if ($parameters) {
        // Make sure the breadcrumb is updated when node title changes.
        $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['node:' . $parameters['node']]);
        $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['url']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module installed.

Comment: Are they actually linked in the menu? How are they connected otherwise? Aliases don't imply cache dependencies.

Comment: Normally you don't solve caching issues in hook_node_update(). The GraphQL plugin building the breadcrumb has to add the cache tags and then they are invalidated automatically when a node is saved.

Comment: i did tried to add node cachetag to breadcrumbs as i mentioned in my edit, and it didn’t work, maybe i should add another cacheTag, what i'm missing ?

Comment: @Kevin no they are not linked in the menu, auto generated breadcrumbs using Easy Breadcrumb module

Comment: OK, provided that the breadcrumbs have all necessary cache tags, it's still unclear which code is building the GraphQL result. Couldn't find such a plugin in the main module. Do you have an extra module for that?

Comment: No extra module for breadcrumbs, i use the qraphQl officiel module version 3.X i found the Breadcrumb field defined here **graphql/modules/graphql_core/src/Plugin/GraphQL/Fields/Breadcrumbs/Breadcrumbs.php**

Comment: This is the previous version. The [latest update](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/graphql/-/commit/58a9b7464bc6cf4aa78632a0efee83f911c8522e) for this code object was addressing exactly this issue, but I don't know if this update was successful. You could file an issue if you can reproduce the missing cache tags and this version is still maintained.

Comment: Yes i do have this update, it's the last 3.X release installed  !

Comment: Can you confirm the update was successful? For example by checking that the cache tags you've added to the breadcrumbs end up in the cached response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the caching implementation of GraphQL 3.x field plugins, but as far as I can tell this code (even after the [latest update](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/graphql/-/commit/58a9b7464bc6cf4aa78632a0efee83f911c8522e#45c4cae6746ce693a0205138af1784fb108514ba) from 2018) doesn't collect the breadcrumb metadata because it only gets the links:

```
protected function resolveValues($value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
    if ($value instanceof Url) {
      $resolve = $this->subRequestBuffer->add($value, function () {
        $links = $this->breadcrumbManager->build($this->routeMatch)->getLinks();
        return $links;
      });

      return function ($value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) use ($resolve) {
        /** @var \Drupal\graphql\GraphQL\Cache\CacheableValue $response */
        $response = $resolve();
        $links = $response->getValue();

        foreach ($links as $link) {
          yield new CacheableValue($link, [$response]);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

Shouldn't it get the breadcrumb object to add its cacheable metadata?

```
protected function resolveValues($value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
    if ($value instanceof Url) {
      $resolve = $this->subRequestBuffer->add($value, function () {
        $breadcrumb = $this->breadcrumbManager->build($this->routeMatch);
        return $breadcrumb;
      });

      return function ($value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) use ($resolve) {
        /** @var \Drupal\graphql\GraphQL\Cache\CacheableValue $response */
        $response = $resolve();
        $breadcrumb = $response->getValue();
        $links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();

        foreach ($links as $link) {
          yield new CacheableValue($link, [$response, $breadcrumb]);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```